# Why is the val() function returning [object Object]?

Tags: jquery

Html code:

```
   <div data-role="popup" id="popup-activity">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Error</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
            <h3 id="error" class="ui-title"></h3>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $('#error').val('Please select Activity');                     
 alert($('#error'));
 $('#popup-activity').popup("open");
```

Hi i'm new to jquery.

I'm using jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.js which allows popups as in the above description.
When I open the popup the value in the error id does not show up. In fact it shows empty.
So I've put an alert box to see its value which says [object Object].

Does anyone know how to display the text in the popup?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('#error').val('Please select Activity');
```

should be

```
$('#error').text('Please select Activity');
```

Or

```
$('#error').html('Please select Activity'); 

alert( $('#error').text() ); // or $('#error').html()
```

Because, [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) is for `input, textarea` controls, so you need [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) or [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html).

Answer (score 3):

`val()` is not meant for `h3`, use `html()` or `text()`

Use

```
$('#error').html('Please select Activity');
```

or

```
$('#error').text('Please select Activity');
```